# Increasing number in a text automatically

Tags: macros, counters

Is it possible in Latex to set in the "middle" of a text a field or another thing, that increases a number (without having to do this by hand)?

For example:

```
M-ERF020

M-AUSW030
```

the numbers between the zeros.

The example is from a requirement analysis, which I write for a bachelor thesis. It's a little bit laborious to set up the numbers.

Comment: It would be better if you add some context: how are those string generated?

Comment: ok, I edit the question

Comment: But that doesn't show us how you are producing the numbers or using them. Yes, LaTeX can keep track and produce the numbers but how best to do that depends on your document. Can you post a small compilable example of the way you are using these and what you'd like the syntax to look like?

Comment: If I understand your question right, you should look up what counters are for.

Comment: @cfr actually I am not writing in LaTex, but in Word. I want to "transform" the text what I wrote to Latex. @ musicman yes and no. It is going in direction counters

Comment: If the numbers are already written, what is there to "transform"?  Isn't the transformation simply a matter of Word -> ["transform"] -> LaTeX.  Your comment to @musicman is unlikely to be understandable to many people other than yourself. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is. With the help of counters (which are a key concept in (La)TeX):

```
\documentclass{article}
\parindent0em

\newcounter{DoanCount}
\setcounter{DoanCount}{1}
\newcommand{\DoanString}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{DoanCount}%
  #10\theDoanCount0
}

\begin{document}
\DoanString{M-ERF}\\
\DoanString{M-AUSW}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]